# Libtool prefixes objects but gcov requires them without prefix

Tags: c, gcc, autotools, libtool, gcov

I need to perform some test coverage with `gcov` on a shared library I am working on.

The problem is `libtool` renames the object files from `my-name.c` to `libmylib_la-my-name.lo` and `gcov` is unable to handle that conversion. Everytime I run it, the error `cannot open notes file` is generated.

If I manually rename `my-name.c` to `libmylib_la-my-name.c` after the build `gcov` works fine, so there is no other problem apart the filename mangling.

### Addendum

Trying to provide a minimal working example I discovered the filename mangling happens only when **`lib..._la_CFLAGS` is set** (and also when it is set to an empty value).

```sh
cat <<EOT > configure.ac
AC_INIT(sample,0.0.1)
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR(configure.ac)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(foreign)
LT_INIT
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
EOT

cat <<EOT > Makefile.am
lib_LTLIBRARIES=libsample.la
libsample_la_SOURCES=sample.c
# The following line triggers the filename mangling (libsample_la-sample.lo instead of sample.lo)
libsample_la_CFLAGS=
EOT

touch sample.c && autoreconf -if && ./configure && make
```

Is there a way to avoid the filename mangling operated by libtool or to let `gcov` understand the filename mangling scheme?

Comment: Difficult to diagnose without your `Makefile.am` - you need to supply more information.

Comment: @Brett Ok, sample project provided.

Comment: The filename mangling is performed by automake any time per-target compilation flags are used. That info was buried (as usual) in the [automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Renamed-Objects.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gcov `gcda` and `gcno` files are named after object files. You can run `gcov` from source directory directly on object file or you can use `-o` option of `gcov` to specify the object file and corresponding `gcov` files.

For example I have a small project that builds a shared library. I pass `gcov` flags to make command:

```
make CFLAGS="-O0 --coverage" LDFLAGS=--coverage
```

Object files and corresponding `gcno` files are created in `src/.libs` folder:

```
$ ls -la src/.libs
libtest_la-test.o
libtest_la-test.gcno
```

The source file is in `src` folder

```
$ ls src/
test.c
```

Next I run my test suite and `gcda` files are created:

```
$ ls -la src/.libs
libtest_la-test.o
libtest_la-test.gcno
libtest_la-test.gcda
```

Now I can enter `src` directory and run `gcov`, specifiying object file name:

```
$ gcov -o .libs/libtest_la-test.o test.c
File ‘test.c’
Lines executed:27.08% of 96
Creating ‘test.c.gcov'
```

It is also possible to just run `gcov` on object file:

```
$ gcov .libs/libtest_la-test.o
File ’test.c’
Lines executed:27.08% of 96
Creating ’test.c.gcov'
```

Or even just specifying base name of object file and `gcov` files:

```
$ gcov .libs/libtest_la-test
File ’test.c’
Lines executed:27.08% of 96
Creating ’test.c.gcov'
```

But I would suggest another automated approach that works very well for me, using [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php). I invoke it from top directory specifying paths to source files and object files:

```
$ lcov --base-directory src --directory src/.libs/ --capture --output-file gcov.info
Capturing coverage data from src/.libs/
Found gcov version: 4.8.2
Scanning src/.libs/ for .gcda files ...
Found 10 data files in src/.libs/
Processing .libs/test_la-test.gcda
[…]
Finished .info-file creation

$ genhtml -o html/coverage gcov.info
Reading data file gcov.info
Found 10 entries.
Found common filename prefix "/usr/src/libtest”
Writing .css and .png files.
Generating output.
Processing file src/test.c
[…]
Writing directory view page.
Overall coverage rate:
  lines......: 56.1% (2098 of 3737 lines)
  functions..: 68.8% (139 of 202 functions)
```

Now `html/coverage` directory contains html files that can be easily analyzed in a web browser.

[image: lcov screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Libtool shouldn't change .c file names. However, it *does* change .o file names; this is because it needs to compile libraries twice on some platforms (once to create position-independent code (PIC) for .so (shared) libraries, once to create code which is not PIC for .a (static) libraries).

What you may be seeing is the fact that `gcov` has issues with shared libraries. See "[can gcov deal with shared object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709699/can-gcov-deal-with-shared-object?rq=1)" for details.

If that doesn't fix it, I'll have to agree with Brett that you ned to supply more info.

Comment: This seems to be a different problem: if after the building I rename my test source files (e.g., `mv test.c libsample_la-test.c`) everything works just fine.